# Calendar.sqlitedb file being override with 233kb default on on xcode 4.2 iOS simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

I have an application which uses the EKEventStore for testing i took my Calendar.sqlitedb file from phone and suddenly after i reset the iOS simulator I can't use the file in simulator as it is being overwritten when I launch my application to the default one - I am assuming this is a bug any work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

If i catch your thoughts clearly then, the above scenario don't seem to be bug or an issue.
Well calendar.sqllitebd is the default file for simulator. If you reset the simulator this will write a new one in the same location if one doesn't exist already.